# Conditional Hyperlink in JasperReports 5.0

Tags: hyperlink, jasper-reports, report

I have created several drilldown reports within my report unit and one of them is based on number of transactions (drilldown for more detail).

I want the drilldown to only be available when the number of transactions is greater than or equal to one.

Can this currently be done?

Comment: I can disable the hyperlink by setting the "Blank When Null" option but I rather show the 0 with no hyperlink if at all possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have two fields stacked on top of one another, one with the hyperlink and one without. Set your expression to show the field without the hyperlink when transactions < 1, and show the field with the hyperlink when transactions >= 1.

Comment: What if the transaction number is returned from a subreport?  Should this still work?

Comment: It should -- in the properties window for the subreport, you can name the value that the subreport returns. Use that as your parameter when choosing to show or hide the hyperlink field.

Comment: It seems I have run into a bug as it will not the print the Variable no matter what I enter in the 'Print when expression' box.

Comment: Does your subreport happen before the hyperlinked field in your main report?

Comment: The subreport is within the same band and is not movable. The Evaluation time on the hyperlinked field is set to auto.

Comment: Is the hyperlink in the subreport? Or is it a field in the main report that is also in the same band as the subreport?

Comment: The latter. The hyperlink is NOT in the subreport...should it be?

Comment: No, but I think if they're in the same band, you might have trouble returning a value from the subreport to the hyperlink. Could you try displaying that value somewhere else in the report (maybe once in a band that appears before the subreport, and once in a band that appears after the subreport) to see if the subreport's value is getting passed back to the main report at all?

Comment: I know it definitely passes a value back.  I believe you are correct in that the band and subreport and trying to evaluate the print when expression box is too much to handle on the fly.  For now I am just going to leave the Blank when Null checked before I start moving my data around on the report.  Thank you! I will mark your answer as correct because well, it is.

Comment: Blank when Null sounds like a good way to handle it, given the position of the field and subreport!

Answer (score 0):

Make HyperlinkExpression return null. This works for me.

http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/520247/conditionally-display-link

Answer (score 0):

JasperSoft Reports 6.12.2
Place Text field stacked on top of one another.
Add Print when Expression to display on condition.
In Hyperlink Settings
If do not want to display link then set Link Target : Self and Link Type : None
Else Link Target : Blank and Link Type : Reference and use Hyperlink Expression as per your need.